# Whys is that the zonal (axisymmetric) magnetic field components of Saturn, Bϕ(longitudinal component taken to be ZERO

Tags: astrophysics, geomagnetism

In a paper while calculating the magnetic field of Saturn longitudinal/azimuthal component is taken to be zero. why, has this to do with the dynamo model ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking why assuming the azimuthal component going to zero is necessary for the dynamo model?  Or are you asking if it affects the dynamo model?

Comment: @honeste_vivere the question is  related to the first question in your comment.(assuming the azimuthal component going to zero is necessary for the dynamo mode).

Comment: Oh I doubt it's necessary but it certainly makes the math much easier...